# Problems with MSVCR120D.dll OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

I've been trying to add the OpenCV libraries to a project in Visual Studio 2010. I've added `C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin` to my path and I think I have all the correct directories and libraries

But I keep getting this error:

> The procedure entry point_exception1 could not be located in the dynamic link library MSVCR120D.dll

I've attempted reinstalling the MSVCR120D.dll a number of times but I keep getting the same error, I've installed OpenCV on other computers, it just doesn't seem to like my home computer.

I'm only doing some very basic code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        Mat im = imread("c:/full/path/to/lena.jpg");
        if (im.empty()) 
        {
            cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        imshow("Image", im);
        waitKey(0);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a library built for Visual Studio 13. Not sure it's very easy to combine new and old variants of Visual Studio in the same executable - I suspect not...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're getting a compile time error.

MSVCR120D.dll should be the Visual C++ runtime library for debugging, the "120" == Visual Studio 2013.  That is likely to be incompatible with Visual Studio 2010.

One option is to download and install Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop and upgrade your visual studio projects and solutions.

The other is to link to the Visual Studio 2010 C++ runtime library.

If opencv shipped with Microsoft debug dlls, tsk, tsk, tsk.